# Editing helm-bibtex citations in markdown

Tags: markdown, helm-bibtex

Helm-bibtex can insert one or multiple (with C-space) citation in some markdown document. I have, however, not found a way to edit these citations afterwards using helm-bibtex.

If I call helm-bibtex inside citation `[@first2019<point>]` I get result `[@first2019[@second2020]]`. I would like to get `[@first2019; @second2020]`.

Therefore, I would kindly ask if there is a non-manual way to edit (add, remove and re-order) the bibliography items in the markdown document using helm-bibtex?

Comment: Author here. The function for inserting pandoc citations is super basic and doesn't support adding references to existing citations.  PRs welcome :)

Comment: pls, how to do syntax highlighting of `[@ref...]` in markdown-mode?